# SQL substring statement

Tags: sql

i stumbled across this kind of SQL query which im not familiar with. 
what exaxcly is the "new" thing after building the select statement ?

```
substring((select group_concat(new.card_number,0x0a,new.card_holdername) from 
(select id,card_number,card_holdername from credit_cards) new where new.id=1), 
1, 300)
```

Comment: "new" is just the alias name that was given to the sub-query that selects on 
credit_cards.  Rename all new to wtf and see what happens.

Comment: That code is prodct specific. Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL every `SELECT` statement returns a table. Every table needs to have a name. This is called an alias. You can do the same thing with columns giving them another name for a particular query you are executing

---

In your example intermediate table was called `new` and the query to create it is:

```
select id,card_number,card_holdername from credit_cards
```

In an outer query you can then reference columns from this `new` table like so:

```
new.id
new.card_number
new.card_holdername
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` is the alias, in your example it is alias of this select:

```
(select id,card_number,card_holdername from credit_cards) new
```

So, these are the references from your `new` table:

**new**.card_number,0x0a,**new**.card_holdername ..